# Can you get the url/source for a 'like' on Facebook using the API's?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

What I'd like to do is to get the links, images and video's that a user has shared or liked via Facebook. 
Getting the likes for a certain user is easy, but it only returns name, category, id and created_time. A 'like' doesn't seem to be a thing on it's own (a link actually is).

Is there a way to retrieve the url of the liked item via it's ID?
I'm using the php SDK btw..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$likes = $facebook->api('/USER_ID/likes');

/* Some kind of error control here */

foreach ($likes['data'] as $item) {
    // One API request for each item! Caution with timeouts if too many likes
    print_r ($facebook->api($item['id']));
}
```

Note that you can get more that one `website`, but only one `link`.

Sample output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 7608631709
    [name] => 'House'
    [picture] => 'http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/hs349.snc441607_7608631709_1352247_s.jpg'
    [link] => 'http://www.facebook.com/House'
    [category] => 'Television'
    [website] => 'http://www.fox.com/house http://www.twitter.com/HouseonFOX'
    [username] => 'House'
    [genre] => 'Drama, Mystery, Comedy'
    [network] => 'FOX'
    [season] => 7
    [schedule] => 'Mondays, 8/7c on FOX'
    [fan_count] => 16018912
)
```

Comment: thx that works..   not sure how to interpret [website] here though.

Comment: `website` list is a `Page` element added by the administrator. You can `explode()` it by `"\n"` and you will get an array of URLs

Comment: thx.. im mainly interested in the external links and there the [website] is the same as [link], so not problems there :)